# WordPress async-upload.php returns 500 (Internal Server Error) after uploading a large JPG file

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, media-library

I'm getting an `HTTP Error` message when uploading a big jpg file (about 30 - 40MB) and  I can see `500 Internal Server Error` response in the Chrome dev tools network tab returned by the `async-upload.php`.

The error appears after the file is uploaded. I can see the file in the `wp-content/uploads` directory, so the problem is not related to the uploading process.

I suppose that the problem is related to images resizing process that happens after the file is uploaded. I tried to rebuild thumbnails manually (using several regenerate thumbnails plugins) to prove that the problem is related to the resizing process. All of them failed to resize a large image.

Things I did before posting this question:

- I've increased the memory limit to 256MB in the `php.ini` file (`memory_limit = 256M`)
- set `post_max_size = 256M`
- Set up a fresh WP instance. No plugins, default theme.
- Tested on a different machine (on VPS, same PHP settings)
- I've turned off `mod_security` settings:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_security.c>
      SecFilterEngine Off
      SecFilterScanPOST Off
  </IfModule>
  ```
- I've also tried to change the default image library:

  ```
  add_filter('wp_image_editors', function () {
      return ['WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick'];
  });
  ```

**UPDATE:**

I've just realised that the filter I've applied didn't do anything. I have check the WP source code, and found that default value for this filter is: `['WP_Image_Editor_Imagick', 'WP_Image_Editor_GD']`. I've changed the order, but I didn't have Image Magic library installed, so WordPress has been using GD library anyway.

So I have installed the Image Magic PHP extension to give it try. I've also removed the filter because it's default value works for me.

**Replacing GD library with Image Magic solved the problem.**, but I'm still curious why GD library can't handle such big images. Is there any way to solve this issue in a different way? I don't want to be dependent on third party libraries. I would rather use a standard PHP setup (in case of deploying the site on a shared hosting where it's not possible to install custom PHP extensions).

Comment: Check your error log for errors. A potential candidate is that PHP ran out of memory.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a memory-related issue. I even tried to increase the memory limit to 512.

There's nothing in the error log. I check both: Apache and PHP log files.

I've just updated my previous post. I found a workaround - replacing GD library with Image Magick helped.

Comment: That doesn't prove anything, maybe GD required 513mb. Check the error log and you'll know for sure what happened.

Comment: @Halcyon

You were right! My assumption was wrong. I thought that 512MB is an insanely high value (but I'm not ashamed about my assumption, I know [a guy](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Bill_Gates) who thought that 640 kB is enough ;)) 

I've increased the memory limit to 2048 and set the DG library as a default.  it was able to rescale a large image after I've changed the limit.

But I didn't find anything in logs. I've checked both: PHP and Apache logs.

So it appears that GD is more memory-consuming (at least for this kind of tasks).

Answer (score 3):

If you have upgraded the PHP version. This might cause the old plugin to do so. Same thing happened with me. I upgraded php 5.6 to PHP 7 and same error had occur. When i reinstall the PHP 5.6 it started to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In `wp-config.php` change this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);
```

To

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

For me works!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried most of the thing which are possible still not working, after all, the research I have checked plugin folder disabled and checked its working for me, please disable one by one plugin and check. It's work for me. thanks :)

you can rename to the plugin folder name ( plugins to plugins_old )

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

This is a Server BUG. If you dont't change php.ini, or .htacess, try Upload a PNG file. This tricks work for me!

[image]